# XPath for text between tags

Tags: xml, xpath, contains

I want to verify a xpath with canoo webtest.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="myDivId">Firstname Lastname</div>
```

The space between the firstname and the lastname was created with a "`&nbsp;`".

I tried something like the following but it always fails when I test it with FirePath or the console of Firebug.

```
//div[@id='myDivId' and contains(.,'Firstname Lastname')]
//div[@id='myDivId' and contains(.,'Firstname&nbsp;Lastname')]
//div[@id='myDivId'][contains(text(),'Firstname Lastname')]
//div[@id='myDivId'][matches(text(),'Firstname.Lastname')]
```

Sometimes I don't know really the difference between the versions. It was more or less a try and error after I found 1000 solutions on stackoverflow. But it never works for me :/
I also tried to understand the difference of `.` and `text()` and how contains and matches works. But I cant really figure it out as long as all my test cases fail.

What did I wrong?

Comment: It seems that you HTML tags are missing in you post. You need to include them as code from them to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the problem is, that the nbsp entity is not defined `<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">`
You can also try (should work):

```
"//div[@id='myDivId' and contains(text(),'Firstname&#160;Lastname')])"
```

or

```
"//div[@id='myDivId' and  text() ='Firstname&#160;Lastname'])"
```

`text()` returns only the text of the current element.
 `.` (in  a string context) returns the test of any child of the current element.

In you example there would be no different because the div do not have any child beside of text.

Update:
This seems to be a special **issue of FireFox extension FirePath**.
Even with Firebug the document.evalute will do:

```
var xpath = "//div[@id='myDivId' and text() ='Firstname\xa0Lastname']";
divs = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null); 
d1=divs.iterateNext();
```

But consider the javascript encoding of the nbsp as `\0xa0`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried the expression with &#160;, but firebug did not find the node. When I use only the "Firstname", the node is selected.

Comment: @Andy: If think this is a bug in FirePaht

Comment: You are right. I just implemented it in my testcases - right onto my buildserver - all lights are green. Damn. Why didnt I try that before...thank you for your help. Seems to be a issue with FirePath. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

another possible way is to split up the words, so using this xpath-

```
//div[@id='myDivId' and contains(text(), 'Firstname') and contains(text(), 'Lastname')]
```

Comment: Easy and straight forward idea. I kinda like this, even if its not exactly the same test. +1